# Unable to download "cytofkit" R-package

Tags: r

I am trying to install "cytofkit" R-package with reference from https://bioconductor.riken.jp/packages/3.7/bioc/html/cytofkit.html using

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("cytofkit")
```

and

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("cytofkit")
```

and

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("cytofkit")
```

Nothing seems to work.
Please suggest what to do.

Configuration:
Bioconductor version 3.14 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
R-Studio, Windows

Error:

> Warning messages: 1: package ‘cytofkit’ is not available for
> Bioconductor version '3.14'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer available here: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/128865/
Cytofkit was removed from Bioconductor in version 3.9 http://bioconductor.org/about/removed-packages/